# Urn with marbles, unknown number of colors

Tags: statistics, sampling

When I started with this calculation I thought this was going to be a flashback from school decades ago but now after searching I'm confused if I'm over thinking it or if it's not as trivial as I thought - please point me in the right direction if I am.

Assume an urn with N=1000 total marbles. After pulling 70 without replacement, 11 different colors were drawn with different frequencies. based on only these values, can I calculate the probability there are k colors?

I know 10 < k < 942 but how do I calculate the p for let's say k= 50 or what range the p would be less than 0.05?

Thank you!

Comment: You need an assumption or two: one might be whether each colour is as likely to be drawn as other colours; another might be a prior distribution for the number of different colours. You might be able to avoid the second by using maximum likelihood methods to find a particular estimate but would deny you the ability to assign a probability to your result.

Comment: if I were to assume an equal distribution for all colours then how should I proceed?